# How to appropriately scrape LinkedIn directory

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to build a basic LinkedIn scraper for a research project and am running into challenges when I try to scrape through levels of the directory. I am a beginner and I keep on running the code below and IDLE returns and error before shutting down. See below the code and error:

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
from pprint import pprint as pp

PROFILE_URL = "linkedin.com"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

#use this to gather all of the individual links from the second directory page

def get_second_links(pre_section_link):
    response = requests.get(pre_section_link, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
    column = soup.find("ul", attrs={'class':'column dual-column'})
    second_links = [li.a["href"] for li in column.findAll("li")]
    return second_links


  # use this to gather all of the individual links from the third directory page
def get_third_links(section_link):
    response = requests.get(section_link, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
    column = soup.find("ul", attrs={'class':'column dual-column'})
    third_links = [li.a["href"] for li in column.findAll("li")]
    return third_links
```

## use this to build the individual profile links

```
def get_profile_link(link):
    response = requests.get(link, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
    column2 = soup.find("ul", attrs={'class':'column dual-column'})
    profile_links = [PROFILE_URL + li.a["href"] for li in column2.findAll("li")]
    return profile_links


if __name__=="__main__":
    sub_directory = get_second_links("https://www.linkedin.com/directory/people-a-1/")    
    sub_directory = map(get_third_links, sub_directory)
    profiles = get_third_links(sub_directory)    
    profiles = map(get_profile_link, profiles)
    profiles = [item for sublist in fourth_links for item in sublist]
    pp(profiles)
```

Error I keep getting:
[Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUjBb.png)

Comment: Can you have your app sleep between requests to avoid getting blocked?

Comment: Possibly, but I am not sure how to do that. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `https` to `PROFILE_URL`:

```
PROFILE_URL = "https://linkedin.com"
```